# Can I "import" one namespace into another in the header?

Tags: c++, namespaces

## Foo.h

```
namespace Foo
{
    namespace Inner
    {
        void func (int *);
    }
}
```

## Bar.h

```
#include <Foo.h>

namespace Bar
{
    namespace Inner
    {
        void func (float *);
    }
}
```

## main.cpp

```
#include <Bar.h>

using namespace Bar;

int main ()
{
    int i;
    float f;

    Inner::func (&i);
    Inner::func (&f);
}
```

In `main` the `float *` overload of `func` is available without a `Bar::` namespace qualifier, but the `int *` overload requires a `Foo::` namespace qualifier.

I know I could have

```
using namespace Foo::Inner;
using namespace Bar::Inner;

int main ()
{
    int i;
    float f;

    func (&i);
    func (&f);
}
```

I do *not* want this, I want to refer to `Inner::func` as such in each case.

I also do not want to add `using namespace Foo` to every `.cpp` file which includes `Bar.h` (this is the result of a library refactoring effort, pulling some of `Bar` out into `Foo`, many `.cpp` files already include `Bar.h`).

I view this informally as "importing" `Foo::Inner` into `Bar::Inner`, hence the question title. What I really mean is:

Can I add something to `Bar.h` which will let me refer to the overloads in `Foo::Inner` as `Inner::stuff` wherever `using namespace Bar` is in effect?

Comment: Isn't it simpler to rename one of the namespaces, so as you don't have two `Inner` ones?

Comment: Simpler, yes, but the objective is to refactor stuff out of `Inner` and yet still refer to it with the same nonclemature. `Foo` is a parent library formed out of `Bar` and I want this change to be transparent. There was a reason I wrote `using namespace Foo` instead of `using namespace Foo::Inner` in the first place.

Comment: Ah, okay then. I didn't know that.

Comment: Re: "In `main` the `float *` overload of `func` is available" -- there **are no overloads** here. There are two different functions with the same name, but they are defined in different scopes, so they have no relation whatsoever to each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place using into `Bar::Inner`:

```
namespace Bar
{
    namespace Inner
    {
        using Foo::Inner::func;
        void func (float *);
    }
}
```

This way both overloads can be referred with `Bar::Inner::func`.

Comment: Is it possible to do this for *all* symbols in `Foo::Inner`, not just `func`, in one statement?

Comment: @spraff Unfortunately not. `using namespace` will only allow to refer to them inside of `Bar::Inner` but will not make those names part of `Bar::Inner` namespace.

Comment: Yes, "both overloads can be ..." etc., **because** the code in the answer **creates** the overloading. Without it there are no overloads. `</rant>`. +1.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
namespace Inner {
  using namespace Foo::Inner;
  using namespace Bar::Inner;
}
```

before `main`. See live example [here](http://cpp.sh/8byby)

Answer (score 2):

Writing

```
namespace Inner
{
    using namespace Foo::Inner;
    using namespace Bar::Inner;
}
```

just above `main` does this. If you want to bring in only specific symbols, then write `using Foo::Inner::func` &c.